# spresense sdkでPWM出力する方法

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDKを使ったPWM出力をするにはどのように書けばよいのか分かりません。
サンプルコードも無く、SDKに定義されている関数からも推測しにくかったので困っています。

どなたかご存知ないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
十分なサンプルが準備できず、誠に申し訳ありません。

新しいバージョンのSDKを先ほどリリースいたしました。
その中に、PWMのサンプルプログラムを追加しております。

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/tree/master/examples/pwm

ご利用の際は、お手数ですがブートローダを更新していただく必要があります。
ご注意ください。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。